# Enforce Type constraint when the Type is 'Type'

Tags: c#, types

I want to enforce type constraint when I define a 'type mapping' dictionary, such as this:

```
internal static class BindingResources
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Key== IDialogWindowVM, Value ==Window
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> ViewModelDictionary =
        new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        {
            {typeof(CreateGroupVM), typeof(CreateGroupUI)},
            {typeof(CreateNewNetworkVM), typeof(CreateNewNetwork)}
        };
}
```

I want to ensure that `CreateGroupVM` is of the interface `IDialogWindowVM`, and `CreateGroupUI` is inherited from `Window` class. If these conditions are not satisfied that I shall get a **compilation error** instead of a runtime error.

If this even possible, if yes, how to do it? If no, why?

Comment: No, such a constraint is not possible. You could validate the restriction at runtime or at compile time using a custom Roslyn analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper method.

```
public static Dictionary<Type, Type> ViewModelDictionary
{
    get
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        void Add<U, V>()
        where U : IDialogWindowVM
        where V : Window => d.Add(typeof(U), typeof(V));

        Add<CreateGroupVM, CreateGroupUI>();
        Add<CreateNewNetworkVM, CreateNewNetwork>();

        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting; I guess it comes with no performance penalty?

Comment: I think using generic constraints has no performance penalty.